# Jenkins - Unable to find current origin/dev revision in submodule path 'submodule-project'

Tags: git, jenkins, git-submodules

I have a Jenkins job that pulls a git repo with submodule included in `.gitsubmodule` file. The first time that I pulled the repo, there was no issue, but after I have pushed some changes to the submodule, Jenkins no longer pulls the updated submodule repo. It only pulls the changes made in the main repo.

So I have tried enabling the *"Update tracking submodules to tip of branch"* option:
[image]

But I get the following error:

```
 > /usr/bin/git submodule update --init --recursive --remote submodule-project
FATAL: Command "/usr/bin/git submodule update --init --recursive --remote submodule-project" returned status code 1:
stdout: 
stderr: fatal: Needed a single revision
Unable to find current origin/dev revision in submodule path 'submodule-project'

hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "/usr/bin/git submodule update --init --recursive --remote submodule-project" returned status code 1:
stdout: 
stderr: fatal: Needed a single revision
Unable to find current origin/dev revision in submodule path 'submodule-project'

    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1924)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandWithCredentials(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1643)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.access$300(CliGitAPIImpl.java:71)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$7.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1097)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.RemoteGitImpl$CommandInvocationHandler$1.call(RemoteGitImpl.java:153)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.RemoteGitImpl$CommandInvocationHandler$1.call(RemoteGitImpl.java:146)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:120)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:48)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:326)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:68)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    at ......remote call to IS-MEAN_Slave(Native Method)
    at hudson.remoting.Channel.attachCallSiteStackTrace(Channel.java:1416)
    at hudson.remoting.UserResponse.retrieve(UserRequest.java:220)
    at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:781)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.RemoteGitImpl$CommandInvocationHandler.execute(RemoteGitImpl.java:146)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor442.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.RemoteGitImpl$CommandInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteGitImpl.java:132)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy65.execute(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.plugins.git.extensions.impl.SubmoduleOption.onCheckoutCompleted(SubmoduleOption.java:107)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1188)
    at hudson.scm.SCM.checkout(SCM.java:485)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1276)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:607)
    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:529)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1738)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:410)
Finished: FAILURE
```

My .`gitmodule` file looks like this:

```
[submodule "submodule-project"]
    path = submodule-project
    url = <path-to-submodule-project>.git
    branch = dev
```

Any idea how to resolve this?

Note: I could not find many references for syntax of .gitmodules file, but I think I am using `branch` option correctly. Please point out for any mistakes.

Comment: Did you solve this issue? I'm having the same problem and there is no help in google land for this. We're getting close to dumping Jenkins because we keep getting issue like this (and we don't have those issues in gitlab).

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to give the path of reference repo to use during submodule update.